# Passing a concrete List of EnumMap objects to generic List of EnumMap parameter causes compile error

Tags: java, generics

I have a piece of code that I think should compile, but it doesn't. Here is the code:

```
public class Program {
public void myMethod(List<EnumMap<? extends MyInterface, String>> map)
{

}

public void caller()
{
    EnumMap<MyEnum, String> map = new EnumMap<MyEnum, String>(MyEnum.class);

    List<EnumMap<MyEnum, String>> list = new LinkedList<EnumMap<MyEnum, String>>();

    myMethod(list); //error argument type is not compatible 

}
```

}

MyEnum is an enum that implements MyInterface.

Why does calling myMethod(list) gives me argument type is not compatible?

If I change myMethod's signature to:

```
public void myMethod(List<? extends Map<? extends MyInterface, String>> map)
```

then everything works fine, but I'm still puzzled and wish to know why the original 
method signature does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnumMap<MyEnum, String>` and `EnumMap<? extends MyInterface, String>` are different types (the former is a subtype of the latter). So `List<EnumMap<MyEnum, String>>` and `List<EnumMap<? extends MyInterface, String>>` are not compatible with each other. In general, `List<A>` cannot be assigned to `List<B>` if A and B are different types, no matter what the relationship between A and B is (same applies to any generic type not just List). When you have a bounded type parameter, that is a different story; the compatibility takes the bounds into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

So, given

```
enum MyEnum implements MyInterface { ...}
...
List<EnumMap<MyEnum, String>> as = new ArrayList<EnumMap<MyEnum, String>>();
List<EnumMap<? extends MyInterface, String>> bs;
```

We should be able to assign `bs = as`?

Now suppose

```
enum OtherEnum implements MyInterface { XXX }
...
EnumMap<OtherEnum, String> otherMap =
    new EnumMap<OtherEnum, String>(OtehrEnum.class);
otherMap.put(OtherEnum.XXX, "");
bs.set(0, otherMap);
EnumMap<MyEnum, String> myMap = as.get(0);
MyEnum xxx = myMap.keys().iterator().next();
```

`otherMap` and `myMap` point to the same object but clearly different types. Worse, `xxx` is of tyoe `MyEnum` but is pointing to an object of type `OtherEnum`.

Pointers to pointers in the presence of polymorphism is difficult.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are saying, but how come changing method signature to public void myMethod(List<? extends Map<? extends MyInterface, String>> map) makes the error go away? Shouldn't the error stay?